# TelegramBot authorization

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiogram

I am creating TelegramBot using aiogram and SQLAlchemy to interact with database. I want to start with authorization. All users' phone numbers are stored in SQLite database. When the user runs Bot, it should ask the user to enter phone number. After the user has done it, Bot checks whether this number exists in the database. If so, the user can proceed. If not, Bot should deny access. Could you explain how to implement it in code?

Comment: like with loging on normal page - when user send command then bot should check in database when user last time send command - if it was some time ago (ie. more then 5 minutes ago) then it should ask for number and add current time to database. When user will run next command then it should also check time and update it to current time. And every command will have to check this time and ask for number if previous command was long then 5 minutes ago.

Comment: you say that you're using `aiogram`, but tagged the `python-telegram-bot` library. please reomve the tag ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add column `logged` and create `/login phone` to set it `True` and `/logout` to set it `False`. And then other commands would have to check if `logged` is `True` or `False`

You could also make it like on web pages and keep time when user was logged and block access when left 5 minutes. if left less then 5 minutes then command could update it to current time.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import os
import datetime

database = {
    1079414868: {'phone': '1234', 'logged': datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)}
}

# --- functions ---

five_minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

def do_login(message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    print('[do_login] user:', user)
    
    if user not in database:
        return False
        
    user_data = database[user]

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    #phone = message.get_args()
    args = message.get_args().split(' ')
    phone = args[0]
    
    print('[do_login] phone:', phone)

    # check new phone
    if phone and user_data['phone'] == phone:
        user_data['logged'] = current_time
        return True
    
    return False

def do_logout(message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    
    if user not in database:
        return True
        
    user_data = database[user]
    user_data['logged'] = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)

    return True
    
def check_login(message, check_phone=False):

    user = message.from_user.id
    
    if user not in database:
        return False
        
    user_data = database[user]

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    # check current session    
    if current_time - user_data['logged'] < five_minutes:
        user_data['logged'] = current_time
        return True
        
    return False
    
# --- init ---

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# --- commands ---
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['login'])
async def login(message: types.Message):
    if do_login(message):
        await message.answer("Login: OK")
    else:
        await message.answer("Login: Problem")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['logout'])
async def logout(message: types.Message):
    if do_logout(message):
        await message.answer("Logout: OK")
    else:
        await message.answer("Logout: Problem")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def test(message: types.Message):

    if not check_login(message):
        await message.answer('You have to use "/login phone"')
        return
    
    await message.answer("I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

# --- start ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Running ...')
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

---

**BTW:** Maybe you could even create decorator `@check_login` to make it simpler to assign to commands. Or you should use some event to test login automatically for every command (except `/login`).